# Data is not updated into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a form that I use to insert data into database and a table in which I display the records from the same database. I have the update button on each record displayed.

When I click on it, the data from the database is displayed in each input from the form; I've modified the information that I want and click <kbd>Update</kbd> button from the form.

The problem is that the data I have modified is not updated in the database and is not displayed in the table of my page.

My `index-admin.php` file:

```
<?php
    include("functions.php");

    //fetch record to be updates

    if(isset($_GET['update'])){
        $id = $_GET['update'];
        $update = true;
        $query="SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE id_user= $id";
        $record = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


       if (count($record) == 1 ) {
           $rec = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
            $id=$rec['id_user'];
              $nume=$rec['nume'];        
              $prenume=$rec['prenume'];  
              $email=$rec['email'];  
              $pwd=$rec['pass'];  
              $rol=$rec['rol'];  
        }
    }

?>
```

My form:

```
<form method="POST" action="functions.php">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?> ">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Nume</label>
            <input type="text" name="nume" value="<?php echo $nume; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Prenume</label>
            <input type="text" name="prenume" value="<?php echo $prenume; ?>" >
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?> ">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo $pwd; ?> ">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Rol</label>
            <input type="text" name="rol" value="<?php echo $rol; ?> "  >
        </div>
         <div class="input-group">

           <?php if ($update == false): ?> 
               <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn">Save</button>
           <?php else: ?>
               <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn">Update</button>
           <?php endif ?>

        </div>
    </form>
```

My `functions.php` file:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $nume       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['nume']);
    $prenume    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['prenume']);
    $email      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $pwd        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']);
    $rol        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['rol']);

    $query="UPDATE utilizatori 
                SET nume='$nume', 
                    prenume='$prenume', 
                    email='$email', 
                    pass='$pwd', 
                    rol='$rol' 
            WHERE id_user=$id;";  

    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Date actualizate!';
    header('Location:index-admin.php');
}
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks. Use [parameterized prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using unescaped user data directly in your queries or manually escaping it.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not check for any errors occuring when running the update query?

Comment: Your `functions.php` references the `$_POST` superglobal, while your `index-admin.php` references `$_GET`. You may find it helpful to read more about [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), where you'll quickly realize these do not refer to the same data.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: You dont set `$id = $_GET['update'];` until AFTER you have called `functions.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think that's a red herring. I can't see how it makes sense to include functions.php inside index-admin.php...the form posts back to functions.php directly.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `$id` is undefined within `functions.php`. It only existed in `index-admin.php`, and when the form is submitted, that code is not running. Web applications are *stateless* and variable values do not persist between requests. Nor are variable values magically passed between separate script files (unless they are called within the same request via an "include" or "require" statement).

However you've actually partially solved that. You have already placed the ID within a hidden field in your form when index-admin is being loaded. Now you just need to create a new variable to read it in functions.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
  $id = $_POST["id"];
```

---

As a separate point, I can't see why you also wrote `include("functions.php");` within the index-admin script...your form posts back directly to functions.php, rather than to index-admin.php. It makes no sense to include functions.php within that page...it won't do anything useful as far as I can see.

---

Please pay attention to the warnings within the comments about SQL Injection. This is a serious vulnerability and you should fix it as soon as possible, preferably before you commence testing your code (so that you don't have to re-test it once you've re-written the query code).